# module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:11)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to programming and i'm following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEmjBEDyVSY&t=589s) However, i keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/app.js 10:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|   render() {
>     return <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>; 
|   }
| }
 @ ./src/index.js 1:0-38

webpack 5.45.1 compiled with 1 error in 103 ms
```

When i run: `npm run dev`

**App.JS**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>; 
  }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app"); 
render(<App name='matt' />, appDiv);
```

Comment: Do you have a JSX loader?

Comment: Not a clue. How do i install it?

Comment: How did you create the project?

Comment: By following i tutorial i linked, i have 'babel-loader' if that's what you mean?
(sorry about this i'm new)

Comment: Did you follow the previous video? https://youtu.be/6c2NqDyxppU?list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kCLWnGmK0jUBmGLaJxvi4j&t=376 he installed `@babel/preset-react` https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react/

Comment: Yes and i'm even using the config from his Github.

Comment: May you share that?

Comment: Yeah @LogicalDev I think we need to see the package.json to be able to help a bit more :)

Comment: And maybe also share your webpack config?